# Reading the metadata (blob and container name) from azure functions using python, but during processing it says NoneType

Tags: python, python-3.x, azure, azure-functions, azure-blob-storage

Below is the code,

```
import logging
import json, os
import azure.functions as func
import twilio
import twilio.rest
from twilio.rest import Client
def main(myblob: func.InputStream):
    filename = logging.info(f"Python blob trigger function processed blob \n"
                 #f"Name: {myblob.name}\n"
                 #f"Blob Size: {myblob.length} bytes")
    filename = logging.info(myblob.name)
    print(filename)     #output - teamaudio/22108192-9a74-4b6e-a237.wav
    fname = filename.split("/")[1]
    print(fname)
    client = Client(account_sid,auth_token)
```

Error

```
 none type object has not attribute split
```

Expected output:

```
 22108192-9a74-4b6e-a237.wav
```

Please guide on how to fix this issue..

Comment: `logging.info` probably returns None

Comment: @Paolo When i try to import twilio in azure functions, it says module named twilio not found.. Do you know what is the best way to include twilio packages in functions of azure..

Comment: Sounds like you should open a separate question for that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`logging.info` returns `None`:

```
>>> import logging
>>> s = logging.info('test')
>>> type(s)
<class 'NoneType'>
```

so the error is expected.

You want to use:

```
fname = myblob.name.split("/")[1]
```